# how to combine image sequences into video in opencv2.3?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, visual-c++-2008

I am trying to combine image sequences such that it will be a video.I have image sequences which are split into frames of 200 numbers.
Please anybody tell me how can I combine them and make a video clip in opencv 2.3. I am using it in visual studio c++ 2008.
Actually firstly I have tried and also asked in this site also to display multiple images in continuous but didn't  get proper answer.

So can anyone give me suggestion for combining image sequences to form video.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623394/how-to-write-video-file-in-opencv-2-4-3

Answer (score 0):

Use [VideoWriter](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/cpp/highgui/VideoWriter) from HighGUI.

```
Mat frame;
VideoWriter record("RobotVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 
    30, frame.size(), true);

record << frame;
```