# Changing the framerate of a movie with OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any solution to recode a movie file to a different framerate with OpenCV and C++?

Comment: You can set the `fps` in the VideoWriter constructor

Comment: since you decode and encode the image during your framerate conversion you'll probably change the video content, too. Do you want to create/delete (additional) frames, or do you just want to tell a videoplayer at which framerate the presented video file has to be played? E.g. input: 4 seconds video with 30fps = 120 frames in total. Output: video file with 120 frames that should be played with 15 fps by a player or a video file with 240 frames that will be played with 30 fps. Both will look similar (if the player supports the feature)

Comment: I need to normalize a huge bunch of videofiles to a framerate of 10 fps without writing to harddisk. There are several other computations done after but the video itself is not relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623394/how-to-write-video-file-in-opencv-2-4-3