# How to make video with sequence images by opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video

I am making a small project on extracting video frames and remake it into video.
How to make sequence images back to video again?

Here is part of my extracting video frames code.

```
if (n_frame % 3 == 0)
        {
            //Save an image
            sprintf(filename, "frame%.3d.jpg", n_save++);
            imwrite(filename, frame);
            cout << "save: " << filename << endl;

        }
```

I named my images frame000, frame001, frame002....etc.

I am using opencv 2.4.11.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Visit [THIS PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623394/how-to-write-video-file-in-opencv-2-4-3?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write video file in OpenCV 2.4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623394/how-to-write-video-file-in-opencv-2-4-3)

Answer (score 1):

you used `FFmpegFrameRecorder`

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Video_images";

```
        File folder = new File(path);

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles.length > 0) {

            iplimage = new opencv_core.IplImage[listOfFiles.length];

            for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++) {

                String files = "";

                if (listOfFiles[j].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[j].getName();
                    System.out.println(" j " + j + listOfFiles[j]);
                }

                String[] tokens = files.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
                String name = tokens[0];

                iplimage[j] = cvLoadImage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Video_images/" + name + ".jpg");

            }
```

recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(Constn.SS, 480, 480);

```
        try {
            recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
            recorder.setFrameRate(0.4d);
            recorder.setPixelFormat(0);
            recorder.setVideoQuality(1.0d);
            recorder.setVideoBitrate(4000);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recorder.start();
            int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            resp = "Slept for " + time + " milliseconds";
            for (int i = 0; i < iplimage.length; i++) {
                long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                if (t < recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                    t = recorder.getTimestamp() + 1000;
                }
                recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                recorder.record(iplimage[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need VideoWriter - http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html

Once you construct it with desired file type and path, you feed it with Mat objects containing frames using << operator - i.e.

```
auto frame = cv::imread("somePicture.png");
auto writer = cv::VideoWriter("out.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 24, frame.size());
writer << frame;
writer.release();
```

The code above will read frame from file, feed it into a video file which has 24fps and MJPG format and AVI container and then the release() method will close the writer.